# how to keep my javascript function to static file after build?

Tags: reactjs, function

I used react with material-UI and Nextjs,i write a global function in my component,But after execute build,i can not find the javascript function anymore in the static file,i want to keep the javascript function to the static file after build,for that i can call it from webview,now i have no idea about this question ,thanks for help!
[code like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpmEK.png)

```
var setDialogVisible;
function testOpen() {
  MaxWidthDialog.handleClickOpen();
}

export function testClose() {
  ddeeff();
  return 'finish';
}

export default function InfoDialog(props) {
  const title = typeof (props.data) === 'undefined' || typeof (props.data.title) === 'undefined' ? '注意' : props.data.title;
  const content = typeof (props.data) === 'undefined' || typeof (props.data.content) === 'undefined' ? '内容' : props.data.content;
  const okbutton = typeof (props.data) === 'undefined' || typeof (props.data.okbutton) === 'undefined' ? '确定' : props.data.okbutton;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const [fullWidth, setFullWidth] = React.useState(true);
  const [maxWidth, setMaxWidth] = React.useState('sm');

  setDialogVisible =
    () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };

  const handleClose =
    () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };

  const handleMaxWidthChange =
    (event) => {
      setMaxWidth(event.target.value);
    };

  const handleFullWidthChange =
    (event) => {
      setFullWidth(event.target.checked);
    };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      <Dialog
        fullWidth={fullWidth}
        maxWidth={maxWidth}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="max-width-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="max-width-dialog-title">{title}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            {content}
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            {okbutton}
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

i call `setDialogVisible` function from my webview

Comment: You would have to have the variable in the global scope of your target, for a browser this would be `window` i.e. `window.variableName` will be accessible in the console or external javascript as `variableName`.

Comment: Thanks let me try it

Comment: i try it and i get a  ‘Uncaught ReferenceError: setDialogVisible is not defined’ when i call the function from webview

Comment: i found i have not write the function in my current page for that it can not work properly,so  i move the function from sub page to the index page,now it's work properly thanks a lot